# Main text not playing nice with fixed scrolling buttons

Tags: html, css

On first load of the html main text is offset to the right due to the scroll buttons, but it jumps to center after you begin to scroll. After going to any other page, main text does not appear until you begin to scroll down the screen.

I am not experienced at all in html and have used chatgpt to help write it.

Here is my script:

```
</script>
    function scrollToElement(elementId) {
      var targetElement = document.getElementById(elementId);

      if (targetElement) {
        targetElement.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'smooth',
          block: 'start',
        });
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
      var activeSection = document.querySelector('section:not([style*="display: none"])');
      var scrollBtns = activeSection ? activeSection.querySelector('.scroll-btns-section') : null;

      if (scrollBtns) {
        if (window.pageYOffset > 150) {
          scrollBtns.style.position = 'fixed';
          scrollBtns.style.top = '0';
        } else {
          scrollBtns.style.position = 'sticky';
          scrollBtns.style.top = '0';
        }
      }
    });

    function showPage(pageId) {
      document.querySelectorAll('section').forEach(function(section) {
        section.style.display = 'none';
      });

      var selectedSection = document.getElementById(pageId);
      if (selectedSection) {
        selectedSection.style.display = 'block';

        scrollToElement(pageId + '-section1');
      }

      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
</script>
```

Heres my CSS styles for the elements:

```
.scroll-btns-section {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      padding: 30px;
      min-height: 100vh;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .scroll-btns-section a {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #333;
    }

    main-content {
      flex: 1;
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 0;
      background-color: #fff; 
    }
```

I have tried changing various styling because I think the issue has to do with the interactions between the positioning of the elements. I have also tried using chatgpt but it has not been very helpful with this issue. As I am not very familiar with html I can't figure out what should go in the script section.

Comment: Please include the HTML for your page so others can reproduce the issue